# condor: unmatched quotes when submitting bash jobs

Tags: bash, condor

I wrote a conder script for a job and use `condor_submit` to submit this job. Below is my script:

```
Executable=/bin/bash
Arguments=" -c "" command_to_run -d -f"" "

initialdir= /path/
output=/path/out
error=/path/err
log=/path/log
universe = vanilla 
Getenv = true
Queue
```

As seen above, the executable is `bash` and I use `-c` to pass the command as a string to bash. The job gets submitted fine, but I get the following error message in `err` output file:

```
command_to_run: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
command_to_run: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This is simply bash complaining about unmatched double quotes. But double quotes look fine to me. I don't know what the problem is. It seems like it is a condor problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Does Condor use doubled double-quotes to embed a double quote?  Most shells use backslash double quote.

Comment: Yes. According to condor manual page, "There are two permissible formats for specifying arguments. The new syntax supports uniform quoting of spaces within arguments; the old  syntax supports spaces in arguments only in special circumstances."
I am using the new syntax. I even tried the old syntax, and I got the same error. For the old syntax, I used `Arguments= -c \" command_to_run -d -f \"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just passing `-c` to bash then single quoting should be sufficient (unless you're trying to embed variables):

```
Arguments=" -c 'command_to_run -d -f' "
```